# Normalization: is it done good?

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema, database-normalization

I am creating game review database. I am new at this, but I am trying my best. Little bit about database: The system is simple, user fill out php form, where he is insert his name, email when choose feedback between is it good or bad and leave a comment/suggestion. I am adding photo how it looks visually, I am just sorry for external link, I can't upload here:[Visual database](http://oi43.tinypic.com/2m2ygt3.jpg)

So here is my tables and the process how I went through normalization:

```
(I believe this is 1NF, correct me if I am wrong)

Table_review { 
    User ID 
    User name
    User email
    Feedback
    Comment
}    


(I believe this is 2NF, correct me if I am wrong)

Table_user { 
    User ID 
    User name
    User email
    Comment
}

Table_review { 
    Feedback ID 
    Feedback
}

(I believe this is 3NF, correct me if I am wrong)

Table_user { 
    User ID 
    User name
    User email
    Comment
}

Table_review { 
    Feedback ID 
    Feedback
}

Table_user { 
    User ID 
    User name
    User email
    Comment
}

Table_whole { 
    User ID 
    Feedback ID
}
```

**My questions:**

Is it normalized?

Should "Table_whole" include its own ID?

I am saying thank you for any help, because I am really running out of time..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: @JohnConde: There's no code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- The user can make as many comments as they like
Table_review { 
    User ID 
    Game ID
    Feedback ID
}    

Table_feedback {
    Feedback ID
    Comments
    TimeStamp
}

-- Now users can comment on what other users think 
-- but only to one level of nesting
Table_feedback_comments {
    Feedback ID
    User ID
    Comment
    TimeStamp
}

-- a user can only rate a game once, but they can change their rating over time
-- For example more content was added and the user likes this 
-- and wants to reflect that in their rating
Table_rating {
    Game ID
    User ID
    Rating
}

Table_user { 
    User ID 
    User name
    User email
    Comment -- something that describes the user
}

-- Even if you have only one game you can still store it in the database
Table_game {
    Game ID
    Game Name
    -- other columns used to represent a game
}
```

Comment: The thing is the game is just one. Its app promotional website, where users fill out their opinions/reviews. And as the minimum requirements I need three relational entities. How it would be if I would store date into database?

Comment: What do you mean "the game is just one" do you mean there is only one game?

Comment: Yes, where is only one game for android phone. So people come to the website and they can review that game.

Comment: okay, I will reformat my answer so that there are entities and none of them are a game.

Comment: Thanks, it should help!